# How to define a product on formal power series (pseudo-differential operators)?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, operators

I am used to working with the set of (algebraic) pseudo-differential operators, which consists of formal power series in the symbol $D$ (differentiation operator) of the form
$$X = \sum_{j=-\infty}^n f_jD^{j}.$$
On this set we can define a natural product defined on monomials by
$$ fD^n\circ gD^p = \sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{n}{k}fg^{(k)} D^{n+p-k},$$
where $g^{(k)} = D^k(g)$ and the binomial coefficients are generalized for negative values of $n$ as 
$$\binom{n}{k} := \frac{(n-k+1)\cdots (n-1) n}{k!}.$$
Then the product is extended by linearity on the whole set. And I would like to define this product in *Mathematica*.

I know it is possible to define functions on patterns such as

```
d[x_^n_Integer] := n*x^(n-1);
```

to compute the purely symbolic differentiation. Is there any way to have the same approach to my problem? I tried something like

```
Prod[f_*Z_^n_Integer, g_*Z_^p_Integer,x_,cut_] := Sum[f*D[g,{x,k}]Z^(n+p-k),{k,0,cut}]
```

but I'm not even close to a proper definition... Any idea?

Thank you,
Ann

Comment: The documentation for `NonCommutativeMultiply` has an example that shows how to implement a simple algebra for differential operators, this might be a good place to start!

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at it :)